# AngularJS textbox value undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive wherein it copies the value of textbox1 to textbox2.

```
function myCopyText() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            $('#textbox2').val($('#textbox1').val())
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the textbox field:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" ng-model="vm.textbox1" my-copy-text />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" ng-model="vm.textbox2" />
```

It works fine until I submitted the form wherein `vm.textbox2` is always undefined. But if I manually inputted a value on textbox2, `vm.textbox2` is able to display the value.

I find it weird that when the directive do the value assignment, `vm.textbox2`'s value is always undefined not until I manually set a value by typing it in.

Comment: you are using the same `id="textbox1"` for two inputs

Comment: `$('textbox2')` is looking for an element, you forgot `#` to depict an ID

Comment: Sorry, have modified the snippet above. Just some typos when placing them here but anyway.. still doesn't work.

Comment: That's by design. Why don't you just use the same ngModel for both inputs?

Comment: I am already using ngModel on the textbox.

Comment: You are using different ngModel for each input field, if you need to replicate, use the same ngModel for both

Comment: Basically, I need ng-models for each as the textbox2 have something else behind that I didn't place here just for demo purposes. So textbox1 and textbox2 values are not really the same.

Comment: this is a backward way of doing this.  If you want to have the `ng-model` of  `textbox2` to have the same value as `textbox1`, just use `angular.copy` to copy the value from one variable to the other, don't try to extract the HTML and then push back into the HTML for angular to extract back out again.

Comment: Why used `jQuery`?

Comment: Because I need to reuse some jquery plugins in my angularjs application. I have found someone with a similar situation as mine. I experience this also using a jquery bootstrap datepicker and the ng-model doesn't pick up the value of the input. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659417/angular-ng-model-not-binding-jquery-date-picker-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. The angular digest kicks in when you change the value via the 
`input/change` event therefore val() will not trigger the `setViewValue`, so the model value will not be updated.

This directive will replicate the value from the model/view to the name you pass in the replicate-to attribute:

```
function replicateTo($parse) {
   return {
        scope: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
             var target = $parse(attr.replicateTo);

             var angularRender = ngModelCtrl.$render;

             ngModelCtrl.$render = function(){
                angularRender();
                target.assign(scope, ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
             };

             ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
                target.assign(scope, ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
             });
        }
    }
}

<input type='text' ng-model="vm.textbox1" data-replicate-to="vm.textbox2"/> <br>
```

Comment: This is binding from textbox1 to textbox2 but the problem still persists when submitting the form. `vm.textbox2` still have an `undefined` value unless I manually input a value on textbox2.

Comment: I've tested here and it is working as expected, can you show me your html?

Comment: Nevermind, you missed the name property which is required to generate the query string  in the submit event

Comment: name is not required as I get values from the ng-model and pass via ajax. As i've said also, i can get the value of textbox1 but not textbox2

Comment: Okay, can you provide a complete example? I'm sure the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Here you go. This first fiddle (base on your given solution) seems to be working > https://jsfiddle.net/egne9gw6/ But this second one doesn't seem to be > https://jsfiddle.net/egne9gw6/1/. Please check console for output. Thanks!

Comment: If the first fiddle, based on my solution is working what is the question? Go ahead and use my solution. The second one won't work because, as I've said in my answer, the JQuery method val doesn't trigger changes in the model